# Why the size of array which is float64 dtype is smaller than the array which is float32 dtype?

Tags: python, arrays

Float64 array and float32 array mentioned in the title are the same array before transferring the dtype.

```
>>>tf.data
array([[ 0.4323222 ,  0.43547374,  0.44253287, ...,  0.47413033,
         0.47939426,  0.48931041],
       [ 0.43846995,  0.44194463,  0.44968641, ...,  0.47143713,
         0.478816  ,  0.49225217],
       [ 0.45199326,  0.45617312,  0.46540445, ...,  0.46566921,
         0.47759479,  0.49858749],
       ...,
       [ 0.28666443,  0.29013845,  0.29773292, ...,  0.34627852,
         0.34814295,  0.34780815],
       [ 0.28523368,  0.29085371,  0.30313784, ...,  0.33980089,
         0.34118292,  0.34012163],
       [ 0.28374609,  0.29204369,  0.31018677, ...,  0.32426074,
         0.32583919,  0.32578641]], dtype=float32)

>>>data
array([[ 0.43232219,  0.43547375,  0.44253288, ...,  0.47413034,
         0.47939425,  0.48931042],
       [ 0.43846994,  0.44194463,  0.4496864 , ...,  0.47143714,
         0.478816  ,  0.49225218],
       [ 0.45199327,  0.45617312,  0.46540444, ...,  0.46566923,
         0.47759479,  0.4985875 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.28666442,  0.29013845,  0.29773293, ...,  0.34627851,
         0.34814295,  0.34780817],
       [ 0.28523367,  0.2908537 ,  0.30313784, ...,  0.33980089,
         0.34118291,  0.34012163],
       [ 0.2837461 ,  0.29204368,  0.31018678, ...,  0.32426075,
         0.3258392 ,  0.32578641]])
>>> tf.data.dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> data.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(tf.data)
6836
>>> sys.getsizeof(data)
112
```

Why float64 array is 112, but float32 array is 6836?

**********************I can't answer my question*************************

**********************There is my answer*********************************

Oh, I know the answer, thanks for the answers from @user2357112 and @user2699. 
The data is just a pointer to the real object which is saved on other place. And there are some test in my terminal for the "size_question".

```
>>> c=np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
>>>c.dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> sys.getsizeof(c)
112
>>> e=np.int32(c)
>>> sys.getsizeof(e)
112
>>> f = c.astype(np.int32)
>>> sys.getsizeof(f)
512
>>> e=np.int8(c)
>>> sys.getsizeof(e)
212
>>> f = c.astype(np.int8)
>>> sys.getsizeof(f)
212
>>>
```

Comment: Probably since `sys.getsizeof` isn't doing what you expect it to.  For exampe see https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609.

Comment: Also, you'll get better answers if you include code that can be run, not just console output.  Right now, `data` and `tf.data` could be any size.

Comment: @user2699 Thank you. I just thought it maybe clearer in the format of console output. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` array isn't flagged as owning its data; it's a view of some other object. If an array doesn't own its data, [`ndarray.__sizeof__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e06d3614182e7b97d5e0d90291642027d147744b/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L1967) doesn't count the size of the data towards the size of the array.

Comment: Oh, in my mind, I understand it that the really object of array is not in "data" for example. "data" is just a pointer to the really object. Is that what I understand right?

Comment: But when it is the really object? And when it is just a pointer? emmmmm...

Comment: I have known the answer. Thanks！